# How can I use the plus operation for a column in SQL Server with the result in the next row?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server that I want to plus amount of a specific column and have the result **in next row**.

How can I do that?

Comment: Adding an example of your data, what you'd like the query to return (and what you've tried already) would help making your question more clear.

Comment: Not easily possible with SQL Server 2008 because it lags the `lead()` function that is available in other DBMS and SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

> I want to plus amount of a specific column and have the result in next row.

In case you are looking to insert another from the previous row after adding certain amount, you could use the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2 + <additional amount>, Col3
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    <Criteria to select that row of interest>
```

In case you are looking to select all the rows in a table and `aggregate` the amount column and show the result in a separate row, then you could use the following:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT '', SUM(Col2), '' FROM MyTable
```

Comment: you know guys for example I have one column with data: 3,5,6,7,8. I wanna plus these together and have the result in next row???

Comment: The second query in the answer does this.